# Google Invisible reCAPTCHA onSubmit not being found

Tags: javascript, jquery, recaptcha

I'm trying to use the Google Invisible reCAPTCHA and I'm getting a bit stuck on the first part.

I need to validate the form fields first (using h5Validate) then if they are valid submit the token. When I try to use the bit below it doesn't seem to validate the form and then in my console it states that it cannot find the function onSubmit.

Any thoughts how I could achieve this?

```
$('.user_contact_form').each(function() {

    var $this = $(this);

    $this.h5Validate();
    $this.ajaxForm({
        target: 'contact_form_wrapper',
        url: '/contact-form',
        type: 'post',
        beforeSubmit: function(arr, $form, options) {
            contactShowHide();
            function onSubmit(token) {
                $this.submit();
            }
        }
    });

});
```